# Typescript mind the order of instantiation in an Object literal?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using the latest Typescript version :`2.6.2`.

I'm encountering a bizarre situation where if I do `foo({a:1,b:2})` - things don't work whereas if I do :  `foo({b:2,a:1})` - they do work.

I have a generic class  , an interface which has 2 properties and a function.

Here is the code :

```
class MyClass<T>  {
    value: T;
    next(value: T): void {
  }
}


export enum StateKey { backlogItems='backlogItems'}


export interface State {
    backlogItems : number[];
    [key: string]: any
}

class A {

    private subj = new MyClass<State>();

    public set<T>(name: StateKey, state: T) {
        this.subj.next({  backlogItems: [...this.subj.value.backlogItems] ,
                         [name]:state      //<--- error here
                       })        
    }    
}
```

I get an error :

> ```
>  Argument of type '{ [name]: T; }' is not assignable to parameter of
>  type 'State'.   Types of property 'backlogItems' are incompatible.
>      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
> ```

But If I change the order of the literals in the object  :

from :

```
this.subj.next({ backlogItems: [...this.subj.value.backlogItems], [name]: state })
```

to :

```
 this.subj.next({ [name]:state, backlogItems: [...this.subj.value.backlogItems] })
```

- Then there's no error

**Question**

Why does changing the order makes it compile ?

[***Image proof***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1DnK.png)

[***Typescript play ground demo***](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyClass%3CT%3E%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20next(value%3A%20T)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20enum%20StateKey%20%7B%20backlogItems%3D'backlogItems'%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20backlogItems%20%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20subj%20%3D%20new%20MyClass%3CState%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%3CT%3E(name%3A%20StateKey%2C%20state%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fwill%20cause%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.subj.next(%7B%20backlogItems%3A%20%5B...this.subj.value.backlogItems%5D%2C%20%5Bname%5D%3A%20state%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fwill%20not%20cause%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this.subj.next(%7B%20%20%20%5Bname%5D%3Astate%2C%20backlogItems%3A%20%5B...this.subj.value.backlogItems%5D%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles without errors if you change the string in `StateKey` enum to some other value, like this

```
export enum StateKey { backlogItems='somethingElse'}
```

(the error also goes away if you add more values to the enum)

The compiler is doing [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) and detects that `[name]` in your argument to `next()` function can be only `backlogItems`, which is declared as `number[]`.

So both variants of the object literal are assigning two different values to the same property, that's why order of assignment matters - the last one wins, basically. Compiler reports the error in case when the last assigned value is incompatible with declared property type - `T` is not compatible with `number[]`.

**UPDATE**

Also, to preserve the code and just get rid of the error, you can make the compiler forget about the type it inferred for `name` by assigning it to the intermediate variable with `string` type:

```
class MyClass<T>  {
    value: T;
    next(value: T): void {
  }
}


export enum StateKey { backlogItems='backlogItems'}


export interface State {
    backlogItems : number[];
    [key: string]: any
}

class A {

    private subj = new MyClass<State>();

    public set<T>(name: StateKey, state: T) {
        const key: string = name;
        this.subj.next({  backlogItems: [...this.subj.value.backlogItems] ,
                         [key]:state     
                       })        
    }    
}
```